# How do I sendBroadcast(intent) from myDialog and receive in myActivity?

Tags: android, android-intent, dialog, broadcastreceiver

So, I'm trying to get a handle on BroadcastReceivers and Intent filters.  I have a custom Dialog that I create in MyActivity.  In the Dialog, I have a Button.  When the button gets clicked, I want to send a broadcast that MyActivity's receiver will pick up.  Here's what I have right now:

```
//MyActivity.java
class myActivity extends Activity {

    //MyDialog dialog initialized in onCreate

    ...

    private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //toast "Broadcast received"
        }
    }
}

//MyDialog.java
class MyDialog extends Dialog {

    //m_context = incoming context from MyActivity

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnCLickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction("android.intent.action.RUN");
                m_context.sendBroadcast(intent);
            }

        });

    }

}


//AndroidManifest.xml
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" />
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When I press button1, the app crashes.  Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

in MyActivity do something like this:

```
private BroadcastReceiver _refreshReceiver = new MyReceiver();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("SOMEACTION");
    this.registerReceiver(_refreshReceiver, filter); 
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.unregisterReceiver(this._refreshReceiver);
}
```

and to invoke broadcast

```
Intent in = new Intent("SOMEACTION");
sendBroadcast(in);
```

Comment: You rock.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Hey, I had it working, but now it only works rarely and sporadically.  Do you know of anything that can interfere with broadcasts?

Comment: So now I'm trying to bounce around a few broadcasts and receivers, and it only works rarely.  I want the Dialog's broadcast to be picked by by Activity1.  Activity1 does some stuff and then sends a broadcast for Activity2 to pick up.  However, when I try this, neither Activity is receiving its broadcast.  I think I'll post up the code in a new question.

Comment: the solution i've typed here will only work if your activity is loaded, because the code to register and unregister is declared in the activity. If you want your broadcast receiver to run every time you invoke it you must declare it in your manifest.xml. Here is a sample: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be much easier to register your receiver in code in your activity's onResume method (and unregiser in onPause).

```
BroadcastReceiver rec = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
};
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.RUN");

registerReceiver(rec, filter);
```

Comment: So this chunk would all go in the onResume, and I'd need a corresponding unregister in the onPause?

Comment: It crashes when MyActivity loads when I set it up on OnResume and onPause.

Comment: Stack trace?  This method works well.  I use it in most of my apps.